# Trying to retrieve the values from dropdown using Selenium WebElement into Array or List

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get all the values from the dropdown element into an Array or List. Can you please let me know if there is any delivered function or way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`Select.getOptions()` comes to mind.

Read the [API docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.util.List;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.Example.com/");
    //List the Values
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='m']//option"));
    //Count the Values
    System.out.println(options.size());

    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
    //Print the text
    System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());

    String optionName = options.get(i).getText();
    //If u want to select the perticular Value
    if(optionName.equals("xxxxx")){

    options.get(i).click();

    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If u r satisfied with the above code,pls select the upper arrow "This answer is useful"